# Serializing JSON Object Array (Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm learning JSON and was wondering how to create an array of objects.  I want my JSON file to look like this

```
{
    "Place": {
        "Stores": [{
            "Grocery": {
                "stock": "fruit",
                "distance": 19,
                "size": 12
            },
            "Department": {
                "stock": "clothing",
                "distance": 21,
                "size": 7
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is what my C# classes looks like

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public List<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public Grocery Grocery { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Grocery
{
    public string stock { get; set; }
    public int distance { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string stock { get; set; }
    public int distance { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}
```

So far, I have tried coding it like this, similar to how the examples are on the [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) website

```
Rootobject root = new Rootobject
{
    Place = new Place
    {
        stores = new List<Store>
        {
            Grocery = new Grocery
            {
                stock ="fruit",
                distance = 19,
                size = 12
            },
            Department = new Department
            {
                stock ="clothing",
                distance = 21,
                size = 7
            }
        }
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root,          
    Formatting.Indented,              
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\output.json", json);
```

but I'm getting two CS0117 errors at

```
Grocery = new Grocery
```

and

```
Department = new Department
```

which says that `Store` does not contain a definition for `Grocery`/`Department`

What am I doing wrong here? Did I just make an error in syntax or is there a possibility I am just approaching serializing this the wrong way?  Much thanks in advance for your guy's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object should look like this:

```
 Rootobject root = new Rootobject
    {
        Place = new Place
        {
            stores = new List<Store>
            {
                new Store{
                   Grocery = new Grocery
                  {
                    stock ="fruit",
                    distance = 19,
                    size = 12
                  },
                 Department = new Department
                {
                    stock ="clothing",
                    distance = 21,
                    size = 7
                }
               }
            }
        }
    };
```

I wrote it from my head, so I hope syntax is good. But main idea is that you were creating list of stores and not any store inside that list. You should create some Store using `new Store`

Comment: It worked! thank you so much.  So from what I understand, it didn't work because although the list was created, I was never actually inside of the list when I was trying to add items?